How to keep an additional value when using connect-by in Oracle?
View v_documents stores only the latest flow_id, but each document can have multiple older flows as well.
View v_flow_ids has two columns - flow_id and parent_id, and using this view it is possible to find all the successive flow_ids for one particular document, starting with the latest flow_id.
However, when doing this for multiple documents at once, I lose track of which flow_id belongs to which document:
select ff.flow_id, max(ff.repo_id) as repo_id --d.id would also be necessary here
from (select f.flow_id
      from v_flow_ids f  
      start with f.flow_id in (select d.flow_id
                               from v_documents d
                               where d.id in (28211,14631,28212,14632,28192))
      connect by prior f.parent_id = f.flow_id) t
left join v_flow_additional_info ff on t.flow_id = ff.flow_id
group by ff.flow_id, ff.external_id

Is it possible to somehow also get the document id in the final result? So that each flow_id is assigned its corresponding v_documents.id?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment, the answer is probably "yes" but we cannot tell you what an answer would look like because there is not enough information in the question to be able to understand what you expect as an output.

JOIN v_documents to the other queries and use CONNECT_BY_ROOT, something like:
SELECT ff.flow_id,
       max(ff.repo_id) as repo_id,
       t.id
FROM   (
         SELECT f.flow_id,
                CONNECT_BY_ROOT(d.id) AS id
         FROM   v_flow_ids f 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN v_documents d
                ON f.flow_id = d.flow_id
         START WITH d.id IN (28211,14631,28212,14632,28192)
         CONNECT BY PRIOR f.parent_id = f.flow_id
       ) t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN v_flow_additional_info ff
       ON t.flow_id = ff.flow_id
GROUP BY
       ff.flow_id,
       ff.external_id,
       t.id

However, without some sample data and an idea of what your expected output is, it is impossible to test.
